# How to get rid of a border

Tags: php, html, css, html-table, border

I have a problem with my CSS... There's a border which I can't get rid of even if it has border: 0px;! It's really annoying. I had the same problem before, but I solved it somehow so I tried it with the same code but with no success...

HTML/PHP code:

```
echo "<table class='profileinfo' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' border='0'>";                  
// Check Map
$map1 = "Summoner's Rift";
$map2 = "Twisted Treeline";
$map3 = "Crystal Scar";
echo "<tr>";
if ($row['map'] == $map1) { echo "<td rowspan='10' class='imageframe155pxblue'><div style='background-image:url(images/tournament/SummonersRift.png);'><div></div></div></td>"; }
else if ($row['map'] == $map2) { echo "<td rowspan='10' class='imageframe155pxblue'><div style='background-image:url(images/tournament/TwistedTreeline.png);'><div></div></div></td>"; }
else { echo "<td rowspan='10' class='imageframe155pxblue'><div style='background-image:url(images/tournament/CrystalScar.png);'><div></div></div></td>"; }
echo "</tr>";
```

CSS Code:

```
.profileinfo tr td {
    border-top: solid 1px #000;
    border-left: solid 1px #000;
}
.imageframe155pxblue {
    border:none;
}
.imageframe155pxblue div {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    width:155px;
    height:155px;
}
.imageframe155pxblue div div {
    background-image:url(../images/imageframes/blue.png);
    width:155px;
    height:155px;
}
```

It works if I remove the border-left and -top from .profileinfo, but it has to be there...

Comment: Where does the border show up?

Comment: Why don't you give the borders the same color as the containing div's background color?

Comment: Firefox has a cool adding that use called firebug. This has a nifty feature where you can highlight and element and under the layout tab it shows margins/borders/padding and size - so you can see easily what to change https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: Agreed. Firebug makes it very easy to see why the border is there. It will tell you what the rule is and where it is in your CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

The border is shown because ".profileinfo tr td" is a more specific rule than ".imageframe155pxblue", and it declares borders.

Change your rule to ".profileinfo tr td.imageframe155pxblue" and the border will disappear, or add [!important](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm) to it's declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.imageframe155pxblue {
    border:none !important;
}
```